# Spring "cacheNames" doesn't work with "key"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

I am trying to configure caching for my methods like this:

```
@Cacheable(value = USER_ENTITY_1_CACHE, key = "#userId")
public List<MyEntity1> findEntities1(Long userId) {
//...
}
```

And:

```
@Cacheable(value = USER_ENTITY_2_CACHE, key = "#userId")
public Set<MyEntity2> findEntities2(Long userId) 
{
    //..
}

@Cacheable(value = USER_ENTITY_2_CACHE, key = "#userId")
public Set<MyEntity2> findEntities2(Long userId, boolean deleted) 
{
    //..
}
```

And Evict for this:

```
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = USER_ENTITY_2_CACHE, key = "#userId", condition = "#userId != null")
```

Unfortunately, when I invoke any of this method with the same userId, the result for the second one is cached from the first method. This leads to casting problems and confusion.

For instance,

```
java.util.LinkedHashSet cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

In other words, when I invoke findEntities1 and then findEntities2, findEntities2 is not invoked, but taken from the cache and fails with class cast exception. The same work if I invoke them in reverse order. 
What I really want is that these two caches USER_ENTITY_1_CACHE, USER_ENTITY_2_CACHE don't know about each other and store their own method calls.

I am using RedisCacheManager.

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: Do not define key, remove the keys and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the key defined explicitly and try

Key will get automatically generated based on the argument based.

```
@Cacheable(value = USER_ENTITY_1_CACHE)
public List<MyEntity1> findEntities1(Long userId) {
//...
}
And:

@Cacheable(value = USER_ENTITY_2_CACHE)
public Set<MyEntity2> findEntities2(Long userId) 
{
    //..
}
```

Comment: In my case, it won't work. I have one more method like this: @Cacheable(value = USER_ENTITY_2_CACHE, key = "#userId")
public Set<MyEntity2> findEntities2(Long userId, boolean deleted) 
{
    //..
}
I evict it with @CacheEvict(cacheNames = USER_ENTITY_2_CACHE, key = "#userId", condition = "#userId != null"). In case I don't use keys, I am afraid, evict won't work as expected

Comment: remove the key from evict too it will surely work provided evict operation has has userId as argument

Comment: Won't it delete cache for all the users?

Comment: No unless you provided all entries to it.

Comment: I think I am confused, when should I specify "key" then if that's not the case? Why technically it doesn't work in my case?